# How can I connect a websocket client in java with a websocket server in nodejs?

Tags: java, android, node.js, heroku, java-websocket

I'm developing a messaging app for Android (written in Java) based on WebSockets (library for WebSocket client side: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket, his documentation: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket/1.4.0), but the client seems to be unable to connect with the server (written in nodeJs and distributed with herokuapp).

after some online research I tried to add these lines of code in the manifest, but it seems to not work anyway:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" > 
</uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
 </uses-permission>
```

server code:

```
const SocketServer = require('ws').Server;

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = require('express')().listen(port);
const wsServer = new SocketServer({ server });

wsServer.on('connection', (ws) => {

    console.log('connected');

    ws.on('message', (arrayData) => {

        console.log('a message has arrived');
    });
});
```

client code(main activity):

```
package com.example.chat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectToServer();
    }

    void connectToServer(){
        URI uri;

        try {
            uri = new URI("wss://earthonline.herokuapp.com");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }

        new webSocket(uri).connect();
    }
}
```

client code(webSocket class implementation):

```
package com.example.chat;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class webSocket extends WebSocketClient {

    webSocket(URI uri){
            super(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
        send("Hello, it is me. Mario :)");
        System.out.println("new connection opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int code) {
        System.out.println("closed with exit code " + code);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("received message: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message) {
        System.out.println("received ByteBuffer");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("an error occurred:" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am developing a similar application and see a problem. The @OnMessage handler on the client side is called after the thread that connected the client to the server finishes. Have you experienced the same thing? I have tried tomcat/tyrus libraries, but they all follow the WebSocket JSR though.